# Parameter binding not working in WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-web-api

For below two controllers, `/api/container/dasdada` is returning "a". If I do a `container?value=hello` I do get "hello".  What can cause the parameter binding not to work?

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    return Request.CreateResponse<string>("a");
}
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string value)
{
    return Request.CreateResponse<string>(value);
}
```

I am using Katana to host it:

```
HttpConfiguration apiConfig = new HttpConfiguration();

apiConfig.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
apiConfig.Formatters.Remove(apiConfig.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
apiConfig.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();

app.UseDependencyResolver(resolver)
.UseWebApiWithOwinDependencyResolver(resolver, apiConfig);

app.UseWebApi(apiConfig);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a method with a parameter called `id` for "id" to bind:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string id)
{
   return Request.CreateResponse<string>(id);
}
```

Should return "dasdada" when you access /api/container/dasdada

if you want both parameters to bind you can have a method:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string id, string value)
{
   return Request.CreateResponse<string>(id + ":" + value);
}
```

This should return "dasdada:hello" for /api/container/dasdada?value=hello.

Comment: @s093294 Hey no problem, we all have those days. Now if this answered your question you know what to do *wink* :)